# Left join a query with a cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not really sure whether I can left join the results that I get from a cross apply function:

```
select
iv.invoiceno
,w.warehouse
,iv.invoicedate
,iv.invoicedesc
,iv.status
,iv.billingstart as [BillingFrom]
,iv.billingend as [BillingTo]
,CAST((iv.invoicesubtotal) as NUMERIC(38,2))as [Sub-Total] 
,CAST((((iv.invoicesubtotal+iv.invoicetax)-iv.invoicetotal)) as NUMERIC(38,2)) as [Discount]
,CAST((iv.invoicetax) as NUMERIC(38,2)) as [SalesTax]
,CAST((iv.invoicetotal) as NUMERIC(38,2)) as [Total]
,d.deal
,d.dealno
,ivt.orderno 
,ivt.rectype    
,ivt.rectypedisplay                                
,RTRIM(ivt.masterno) as [ICode]                               
,ivt.description as [ICodeDesc]                            
,ivt.fromdate as [From]                                
,ivt.todate as [To]                                  
,CAST((ivt.days ) as NUMERIC(38,2)) as [days]                                  
,CAST(ivt.qty as NUMERIC(38,0)) as [qty]                                  
,CAST((ivt.cost) as NUMERIC(38,2)) as [UnitCost]                                   
,CAST((ivt.rate) as NUMERIC(38,2)) as [rate]                                      
,CAST((ivt.daysinwk)as NUMERIC(38,2)) as [D/W]                              
,CAST((ivt.discountamt)as NUMERIC(38,2)) as [Discount]                             
,CAST((ivt.extended)as NUMERIC(38,2)) as [extended]                               
,(CASE WHEN ivt.taxable='T' then 'YES' else 'NO' END)as [Taxable]
,ivt.category
,(CASE WHEN (ivt.cost > 0 and ivt.rectype='R') THEN CAST((ivt.revenuebase) as NUMERIC (38,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [subrevenue]  from invoice iv
inner join deal d                                   on d.dealid=iv.dealid
inner join invoiceitemview ivt                      on iv.invoiceid=ivt.invoiceid and iv.invoiceno=ivt.invoiceno
inner join warehouse w                              on w.locationid=iv.locationid and w.inactive<>'T'
left join category c                                on c.categoryid=ivt.categoryid 
left join ordernoteview n                           on ivt.orderid=n.orderid and n.billing ='T'  where iv.locationid='00009V5H' and iv.invoiceno='H513369' and iv.status in ('CLOSED', 'PROCESSED') and iv.nocharge<>'T'         order by iv.invoiceno, iv.invoicedate,c.category,ivt.masterno
```

I wanted to add a left join with this query:

```
select  tot.gldate, tot.glno, tot.glacctdesc,                  
   tot.debit,tot.credit,tot.glaccountid                       from invoice ivt cross apply dbo.funcglforinvoice(ivt.invoiceid, null, null) as tot where ivt.invoiceno='H513369'
```

but when I do that it gives me way more records then there are supposed to be.

This has been executing for a while. Basically the inner cross apply query generates 204 items and I wanted that to be left join with the items from the main query; but I am doing something wrong not sure what exactly. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a WHERE clause or something so you're not returning every record from the invoice table? And I understand you've run the subselect separately, so you know it's returning no more than 204 records for this whole piece: (select iii.invoiceid,tot.gldate, tot.glno, tot.glacctdesc, tot.debit,tot.credit,glaccountid from invoice iii cross apply dbo.funcglforinvoice(iii.invoiceid, null, null) as tot)

Answer (score 70):

Use OUTER APPLY.  Also I'm not sure if the ON clause after the OUTER APPLY is really needed.  If the invoiceid is the same coming out as going in then probably not.

```
Select iv.invoiceno, iv.invoiceitem,iv.invoiceno
   from invoice iv
inner join deal d
        on d.dealid=iv.dealid
inner join invoiceitemview ivt
        on iv.invoiceid=ivt.invoiceid and iv.invoiceno=ivt.invoiceno
inner join warehouse w
        on w.locationid=iv.locationid and w.inactive<>'T'
left join category c
        on c.categoryid=ivt.categoryid 
left join ordernoteview n
        on ivt.orderid=n.orderid and n.billing ='T'
OUTER APPLY dbo.funcglforinvoice(iv.invoiceid, null, null) as tot
```

Comment: Not only is the `on` clause not needed, it's not allowed

Comment: I removed the ON clause based on what Andomar said.  Try again.

Comment: it still does not work I am getting duplicate values... essentially what I would like it to do is fill the columns where the iv.invoiceitemid=tot.invoiceitemid  and where it doesn't match to return null

Comment: You are probably getting the duplicate values because funcglforinvoice is returning more than one row.  Try adding a where clause like this:  "WHERE tot.invoiceitemid IS NULL OR iv.invoiceitemid = tot.invoiceitemid"  This will do the last part of your comment.  However it still may not get rid of duplicates of the function returns more than row where invoiceitemid matches.

Comment: that did the trick but its not doing a outer join its performing a full join

Comment: Do you already have a WHERE clause?  If so make sure you put parens around the 2 parts of the WHERE I put above.  So ( tot.invoiceitemid IS NULL OR iv.invoiceitemid = tot.invoiceitemid )  The first part should take care of the inner vs outer joins.  I'm assuming you mean an inner join vs full.  A full join would imply that you are getting results in the columns for the function where your other columns are null.